# Ideas to Create a Program That Can Match Items in Two Data Grids

Tags: c#, algorithm, datagridview, matching, inventory-management

I'm in the process of creating a program that will analyze two data grids and find possible matches that exist between them.  These two data grids will hold information about carpets.  These two grids are inventories taken at two different times and great discrepancies exist between them.  Sizes of these carpets may be slightly different and descriptions also widely vary.  I want this program to find possible matches between the two grids and consolidate them into one.

I'm looking for ideas on how to start the real meat of the programming, the finding the possible matches.  This will be the most time consuming part of this program and I don't know exactly where to start.

This will be a windows program written in C#.  I have programming experience in C#, but examples and/or main ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is for the data that does NOT have a simple answer.  If you have a data Key, for goodness sake use it.*

Before coding anything, I would first ask myself just what I'm going to search for.  What are your search parameters for 'matching' the two?  Keywords?  Do your carpets have some sort of identifier on them?  Perhaps by pattern?  I'd try and figure this out first before touching a keyboard.  It's probably not a good idea to search by Size.  After all, two 8x8 carpets may have hundreds of different possibilities.

But perhaps there are some similarities between the descriptions.  If the descriptions themselves are in plain English, I would see if I couldn't find a way to remove some very common words, as well as punctuation and replace them with a space.  **Edit:** Also remove capitalization with a ToLower() function call

```
List<String> CommonWords; 
foreach(string a in CommonWords) 
{
    DataBaseA.DescriptionString.replace(a, " "); 
    DataBaseB.DescriptionString.replace(b, " ");
}
```

For instance, let's say that Carpet Description 1 is as follows: 'This carpet is a wonderful addition to any room, with a red floral pattern combined with a beige rustic look'

And Carpet Description 2 is: 'A stylish rustic floral pattern, complete with a contemporary red and beige'

Running the 'common word remover' would remove, let's say the 'A', 'with', 'and', 'this', 'is', 'to'

You would have: Carpet wonderful addition any room red floral pattern combined beige rustic look

And

'Stylish rustic floral pattern complete contemporary red beige'

Then you could go through the string and do a string match, and trigger a 'Data Grid' match if there are over a certain number of matches.

```
string[] ArrayStringA = DataBaseA.DescriptionString.split(" ");
string[] ArrayStringB = DataBaseB.DescriptionString.split(" ");
int DataCounter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < ArrayStringA.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ArrayStringB.Length; j++)
    { 
        if(ArrayStringB[j] == ArrayString[i])
            DataCounter++;
    }
}

if(DataCounter > 4) //Match
```

Now keep in mind that **this is not pretty**.  Doing this will probably take a significant amount of time to compare, as well as maintain, and it is by no means foolproof.  However, it's an idea, and hopefully you can use at least a little bit of it to come up with a better solution.

**Edit II:** When your program runs, I don't foresee this being something that you would want to happen over and over again.  So what I would do is run the program and build a DataGrid of the matches.  Then once you have your matches and everything looks good, ***add Unique Identifier keys to your new data***.  This way you will be able to know *exactly* which is which in the future.

Comment: I certainly like your ideas, especially the ones about taking out common words and such.  I was thinking of using a similar idea to yours, while also factoring in size.  Size might be more important than the description and here's why: there are a lot of carpets with the same description, but different size.  However, some sizing discrepancies exist where i might need to search for a range of sizes.  Maybe create a point system where similarities recieve a high point value and the carpet with the highest amount of points is the most likely match.  What do you think?

Comment: That would add complexity to the program, but you know your data better than I do.  For instance, this point system, what determines a better match than what?  Is 'flower pattern' a 5 point match while 'blue' a 1 point?  Maybe I'm not understanding the question. I've also made a simple edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you the fact that this data will be in datagrids is not important. The datagrids will be backed by something, a list or a table, and this "source" data will be what you have to deal with.

Answering this question is difficult, since you admit you don't know how you want to compare the data. These are the important questions, as I see it:

1. Do the two sources match by column?
2. Will the **KEY**, if not then this provides a simple method for matching. If no, then what fields can be used to match?
3. Are the updates to the newer set of data to be *strusted*, and if not why?
4. Why are you performing this matching? Is it regular, or one-time?

If 1-3 are true, then the answer is pretty simple. Loop through one table, find the matching key in the other table, and use your logic (probably the update time) to determine which information is accurate.

Comment: 1-3 is true, but it's a little more complex than just looping through.  The descriptions are in sentence form, so I can't directly match the sentences.

Comment: If 1-3 are true, why are you matching on sentences? Match on the key.

Comment: There really isn't a key.  There are two inventories that need to be consolidated.  One has ID numbers for the carpets, the other one doesn't.  The IDs were kept on file, but never on the carpets themselves - stupid, i know...  I need to be able to match the information in both inventories which got scattered over the years.  Sorry if I wasn't clear before.